# How do I find the network drivers installed on a network card programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, drivers

I am working with a machine vision ethernet (GigE) camera on a Windows computer. The cameras work with Filter drivers that are installed on network cards. Sometimes, multiple filter drivers from different providers can be installed on the card which causes the camera to malfunction. I need to write code in C++ which will help me list all the drivers that are installed on a network card and then need to find out if those drivers are enabled or disabled. The drivers I am referring to can be seen in the image I have attached.

I have tried using the msinfo32.exe file along with xml tools to find all the drivers I am looking for but this method does not give the state (enabled/disabled) of the drivers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[Network Drivers I am looking to find programmatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNAvc.jpg)

Comment: Have you searched the WinAPI docs?

Comment: I have and unsuccessfully so :( I read a bunch of articles and none of them seemed to be helping me do what I want. I do have a feeling that WinSock will be involved based on what I read but I am clueless about how.

Comment: No, I don't think you're going to find it in WinSock. It will be in the device driver stuff.